# Scalaz task firstCompletedOf

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have two `scalaz.concurrent.Task`s which are performing a HTTP request to different servers.

I want to compose them in a manner similar to `Future.firstCompletedOf`, that is: run them both in parallel and get the result of the first one that successfully completes.

Unfortunately `Task.gatherUnordered` does not what I want since it runs every task to completion before returning the result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do it in `scalaz.concurrent` natively, but this one works for me:

```
import scalaz.Nondeterminism._
import scalaz.std.either.eitherInstance
import scalaz.syntax.bitraverse._

def race[A, B](t1: Task[A], t2: Task[B]): Task[A \/ B] = {
    Nondeterminism[Task].choose(t1, t2).map {
      _.bimap(_._1, _._2)
    }
}
```

In `fs2` - successor of `scalaz.concurrent` - it is `fs2.async#race`

Answer (score 1):

While using `bimap` is indeed correct, there's an alternate implementation:

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.Nondeterminism

def firstOf[A, B, C](ta: Task[A], tb: Task[B])(fa: A => C, fb: B => C): Task[C] = 
  Nondeterminism[Task].chooseAny(ta.map(fa), Seq(tb.map(fb))).map(_._1)

val task1 = Task { Thread.sleep(10000); 4 }
val task2 = Task { Thread.sleep(5000); "test" }
firstOf(task1, task2)(_.toString, identity).unsafePerformSync // test
```

Here I'm assuming that non-deterministic retrieval of results is used to obtain equivalent values for which exact computation time is unknown. So the function incorporates concurrently-performed conversions `fa` and `fb` to the common type. It's good in the cases when conversion time is difficult to compute as well - it selects first result after conversion, for example, some request data extraction in the case of HTTP. For simpler cases, variant of `race` function that performs mapping in parallel is retrieved from `firstOf` as follows:

```
def race[A, B](ta: Task[A], tb: Task[B]): Task[A \/ B] = firstOf(ta, tb)(-\/(_), \/-(_))
```